# how to convert else if in java8

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, option-type, underscore-java

How to change the below code to remove if-else and use Java8

```
List<String> list1;
List<String> list2;
List<String> list3;
String str;
if(list1.contains(str)){
    event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("ABC","ABC1");
}
else if(list2.contains(str)){
    event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("ABC2","ABC3");
}
else if(list3.contains(str)){
    event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("ABC4","ABC5");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it without `if-else`, but for this case, `if-else` would still be better than using streams.

```java
List<String> list1;
List<String> list2;
List<String> list3;
String str;
Map<List<String>, List<Param>> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put(list1,List.of(ABC,ABC1));
paramMap.put(list2,List.of(ABC2,ABC3));
paramMap.put(list3,List.of(ABC4,ABC5));

List.of(list1,list2,list3)
    .stream()
    .filter(list -> list.contains(str))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(list -> event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty(paramMap.get(list).get(0),paramMap.get(list).get(1)));
```

Another solution without using the list as key in `paramMap`:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Param>> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put(1,List.of(ABC,ABC1));
paramMap.put(2,List.of(ABC2,ABC3));
paramMap.put(3,List.of(ABC4,ABC5));
List<List<String>> lists = List.of(list1,list2,list3);
List<String> mList = lists.stream()
                          .filter(list -> list.contains(str))
                          .findFirst()
                          .ifPresent(list -> {
    Integer index = Integer.valueOf(lists.indexOf(list));     
    event.getMessage()
         .setInvocationProperty(paramMap.get(index).get(0),paramMap.get(index).get(1))
    });
```

Comment: It is not advised to use lists as keys for a map as they're not immutable, and if they are, their children are usually not

Comment: @YassinHajaj You're right, but IdentityHashMap would be fine here. Or a list of tuples. Same thing

Comment: @Michael, but would entrySet return the entries in order?

Comment: @GauthamM Ah, right... Yeah, that's unfortunate. `List<Pair<List<String>, List<Param>>>` would work too. Ugly though.

Comment: @YassinHajaj, but is there a better way to map the params?

Comment: @GauthamM I'm thinking, I'll see if I can come with a solution

Comment: @Michael still `Pair` is part of javafx right? I think for this use-case, anything other than `if-else` would make it more complex than the `if-else` :-)

Comment: @GauthamM There are many different Pair implementations, not really any one definitive one. Usually when I write an answer that relies on Pair, I just note that it doesn't matter which specific one you use. Usually people will have something on their classpath for Apache or Guava or something. Worse case, core Java has [SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) which is effectively the same thing.

Comment: Is if-else increased processing time during execution?

Comment: @rahuljain9907, No it doesn't have much of an impact in the normal case. But it depends on the condition you are checking. For your code, you are checking `List.contains`, which is O(n) operation (assuming `ArrayList`). So if the list is too large, it would increase time. But that increase in time is caused due to `contains` method and not because of `if-else`. If you have just three blocks of `if-else`, then it would be more readable to use `if-else` than using streams.

Comment: @Gautham M here in above code i'm not able to get List.of(ABC,ABC1)) here "ABC" & "ABC1" is String

Comment: @rahuljain9907, then you need to use List<String> instead of List<Param> and also `List.of("ABC", "ABC1")`

Comment: @Gautham M yes i tried with  List<String> instead of List<Param> but in List.of("ABC", "ABC1") i'm getting error "The method of(String,String) is undefined for the type List"

Comment: @rahuljain9907, I missed that fact that you were using java-8, `List.of` was introduced in java 9. You could replace that with `Arrays.asList("ABC", "ABC1");`

Comment: Thanks Gautham M its working and can we move this code in java8 functions?

Comment: @rahuljain9907. No. One thing which you could do is move the statement inside `filter` as a `Predicate` variable and the statement inside `ifPresent` as a `Consumer` variable. But that is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it by creating what I'll call a `HoldingObject`, but you can name it with something more close to your business.

I'm using Lombok's `@Value` annotation and also [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9)'s `List#of` factory method

```java
@Value
public static class HoldingObject {
    List<String> list;
    String invocationProperty1;
    String invocationProperty2;

    public void setInvocationPropertyFor(Event event) {
        event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty(invocationProperty1, invocationProperty2);
    }
}
```

Note that doing `event.getMessage()` repeatedly might not be thread-safe if event is accessed through multiple threads

```java
HoldingObject firstObject = new HoldingObject(list1, ABC, ABC1);
HoldingObject secondObject = new HoldingObject(list1, ABC2, ABC3);
HoldingObject thirdObject = new HoldingObject(list1, ABC4, ABC5);

List.of(firstObject, secondObject, thirdObject)
    .stream()
    .filter(object -> object.getList().contains(str))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(h -> h.setInvocationPropertyFor(event));
```

Comment: That is better. Would it be a good idea to move `event.getMessage().setInvocationProperty(holdingObject.getInvocationProperty1(), holdingObject.getInvocationProperty2())` as a method in `HoldingObject` so that the `ifPresent` part looks neat ?

Comment: That is definitely possible too, thanks for the suggestion @GauthamM I'll modify it